# How to sort an array using stack in assembly

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, stack, tasm

I want to sort an array while using the stack:

so first things first I pushed it all into the stack.

then I'm locating the minimum element in the stack, swapping it with the top element popping it out and move it back to the array.

but something isn't right and about halfway there it got messed up (DI is one index below than what it should really be)

```
data segment
   a db 5h,12h,6h,4h,9h
   len equ $-a
   loop_counter db len
   min_index dw 0
   min db ?
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)   
ends

code segment ;TODO: Locate min in stack xchg it with top element copy to array and pop it :|    
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov bx,0
    mov cx,0
    mov cl,loop_counter
push_arr_to_stack:

    mov al,a[bx]
    push ax
    inc bx      
    loop push_arr_to_stack
  
    mov bx,len-1
    mov ax,0
    mov cl,loop_counter
    mov bp,sp
    mov ax,[bp]
    mov bx,[bp]
    mov di,0 
    mov dx,0
    mov si,2
    mov di_check,len-loop_counter 
    
find_min_to_arr:

    cmp bx,ax
    jb  new_min
    mov bx,[bp+si]
    add si,2  
    
    loop find_min_to_arr
    mov min,al
    
    xchg a[di],al
    jmp pop_min
    
new_min:
       mov ax,bx
       mov bx,[bp+si]
       mov min_index,si
       sub min_index,2
       add si,2
       dec cx
       jmp find_min_to_arr
        
pop_min:
        mov dx,[bp]
        xchg di,min_index
        mov [bp+di],dx
        xchg di,min_index
        pop dx
        mov dx,0
        inc di
        mov si,0
        cmp di,len
        je b
        dec loop_counter
        mov cl,loop_counter
        jmp find_min_to_arr
        
b:              
    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h
  
ends
end start
```

Comment: Time to learn how to *debug* your code, and how to step through it instruction by instruction while monitoring registers and their values (as well as the array in memory itself).

Comment: Thats what I did- thats how I noticed the error :|

Answer (score 0):

> first I pushed it all into the stack.

This part is fine although for speed reasons you should forget about `loop ..` and replace it with `dec cx` followed by `jnz ..`

> then I'm locating the minimum element in the stack, swapping it with the top element popping it out and move it back to the array.

Here your code gets very complicated and it contains many errors. Also the code does not perform true swapping between the located minimum and the element at the top of the stack.

I tried amending your code but as is often the case, it is beyond repair. Below is my rewrite that you should study, not just copy!
I have defined the *loop_counter* a **word** variable because that's easier. Additionally I kept it in the `DX` register that was sitting there doing nothing...

### Pushing it all into the stack

```
    mov  bx, dx
push_arr_to_stack:
    mov  al, a[bx-1]
    push ax
    dec  bx      
    jnz  push_arr_to_stack
```

I push the array in reverse so the stack has the elements in the same order as the original array. This is not necessary for the task, but it is simpler and it leaves the `BX` register at zero for use below.

### Locating the minimum in the stack

```
Again:
    mov  bp, sp
    xor  si, si
    mov  al, [bp+si] ; Chosen minimum
    mov  di, si      ; Remember its position
    mov  cx, dx
    dec  cx          ; N elements = N-1 compares
    jz   .c
.a: add  si, 2
    cmp  al, [bp+si]
    jbe  .b
    mov  al, [bp+si] ; New minimum
    mov  di, si      ; Remember its position
.b: dec  cx
    jnz  .a
```

### Swapping it with the top element

```
.c: xchg al, [bp]
    mov  [bp+di], al
```

### Popping it out and moving it back to the array

```
    pop  ax
    mov  a[bx], al
    inc  bx
    dec  dx
    jnz  Again
```

---

The important thing here is that the above exactly does what the task description said.

Comment: The first error is somethin I forgot to delete sorry! And about cx, with each loop finish I do ```MOV CL,loop_counter ``` and every time im decreasing loop counter. and xan you explain this line please ? ```xchg a[bp+di], al```

Comment: @almogbb The `xchg a[bp+di], al` was because I followed the task description to the letter. The exchange was supposed to stay within the stack, something `xchg [di], al` could not do. In other words: I did not see the small caps **a** referring to the actual array.